# Error while ActiveMQ installation

Tags: java, apache, jms, activemq-classic

I'm trying to install ActiveMQ 5.14.3 on windows7 x32.
But i've got some errors while installation.
How can i fix it?

```
jvm 1    | ERROR | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ ([localhost, ID:Admin--49711-
1482610732322-0:1], java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in hostname a
t index 10: ws://Admin-╧╩:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=
104857600)
jvm 1    |  WARN | Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
jvm 1    |  WARN | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancell
Jvm 1    | ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reas
on: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already clos
ed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
```

Here is full output of console: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/19954Acw)

**UPD 1**
My activemq.xml transports part

```
<transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

Comment: Have you changed the hostname of ws transport ?? This what the logs are saying. Post your activemq.xml transports part please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that the ws transport is like this

```
 <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

**Update**

Try with jre 1.7

Comment: Yes, ws transport is equals to yours

Comment: What is the hostname of the machine where AMQ is running ? Try hostname in console

Comment: Oh, there were some cyrillic characters in the hostname of my pc. My mistake(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering on old question but I prefer posting here for further readers.

The solution is to update `conf/activemq.xml` file.

```html
<transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://127.0.0.1:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://127.0.0.1:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://127.0.0.1:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://127.0.0.1:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://127.0.0.1:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```